# QGraphicView doesn't show anything

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I tried to show video using QGraphicView but my code doesn't show anything. What is the problem

```
QGraphicsScene scene;
QGraphicsVideoItem *item1 = new QGraphicsVideoItem;
item1->setPos(0,100);

QMediaPlayer * player1 = new QMediaPlayer;
player1->setVideoOutput(item1);
player1->setMedia(QUrl("/home/1.wmv"));
QGraphicsView view;
view.scale(0.3,0.3);
view.setScene(&scene);
view.show();
player1->play();
```

Comment: change to `QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;` and `QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(scene);`, provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `QGraphicsVideoItem` which you are using as output for a `QMediaPlayer` and are creating a `QGraphicsView` on which you assign a `QGraphicsScene`. But you are not connecting the `QGraphicsVideoItem` (or the `QMediaPlayer`) to the `QGraphicsView` (or the `QGraphicsScene`), so obviously nothing gets shown in the `QGraphicsView`.

Note this is only a guesswork answer based on the incomplete code you provided. In the future, please be sure to include all relevant code/create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You forgott:

```
scene->addItem(item1);
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView(scene);

    QGraphicsVideoItem *item1 = new QGraphicsVideoItem;
    QMediaPlayer * player1 = new QMediaPlayer;

    scene->addItem(item1);
    item1->setPos(0,100);

    view->scale(0.3,0.3);
    view->show();

    player1->setVideoOutput(item1);
    player1->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/user/Musik/musik.mp4"));

    player1->play();

    return a.exec();
}
```